# python find a pattern in string and enclose it in braces

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I am not an expert in regex and trying to do the below.

string 's' can contain pattern `16'h2020:16'h2F20` i.e hexadecimal numbers range. I need to enclose this match in square bracket and return to same string, i.e [16'h2020:16'h2F20].

i did it as:

```
s = re.sub("\d+'h\d+:\d+'h\d+","[\d+'h\d+:\d+'h\d+]",s)
```

But its not working as required. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you need to use [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

```
s = re.sub(r"(\d+'h\d+:\d+'h\d+F\d+)",r'[\1]',s)
```

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "16'h2020:16'h2F20"
>>> re.sub(r"(\d+'h\d+:\d+'h\d+F\d+)",r'[\1]',s)
"[16'h2020:16'h2F20]"
```

Comment: Thanks Avinash !! Does the group number always start from number 1 and from left to right ? In case if I have multiple groups ?